# How to use lambda expressions / Shorten onclicklisteners android studio

Tags: android, button, lambda, textview, onclicklistener

In my customer adapter class for recyclerview I am adding click listeners on each button within single item. However, I have quite few buttons to which I need to add the click listeners and doing so, is making my my code very long as I have around 3-4 listeners. I was wondering whether it possible to shorten the click listener code? During my research on this, I came across lambda expression however either these don't work in customer adapters or I can't seem to get them working.

This is an example of what I am using atm: Works fine, however, I have 4 of them so I want to reduce the code as much as possbile;

```
myHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

From research I tried this:

```
myHolder.button.setOnClickListener(view -> button.setText("Working"));
```

This code give error saying: lambda expressions are not supported at this language level

I also tried this:

```
myHolder.button.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    //Do something
    });
```

it gives the same error as above.

Is there any other ways to make the code shorter?

Any help would be nice. Thanks.

EDITED:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.project.example'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "6.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

..... 
dependencies

Comment: If you want to use Java 8 features (not all of them, mind), you can [compile using Jack](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 8 language features to be used in Android Studio requires Jack compiler. 
From Android Studio 2.1 supports Jack compiler. You need to update android studio if current version is less then 2.1. Add following entry in build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yourapplicationID"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 11
        versionName "3.1"
        jackOptions {
          enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
}

dependencies {
.....
}
```

Comment: Please see edit, where should I put the jackOptions  code. I am getting error if I put it above buildTypes

Comment: Add that in defaultConfig

Answer (score 3):

To support Java8 you have to enable the jack compiler. In order to do so add this to your build.gradle

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see edit, where should I put the jackOptions  code. I am getting error if I put it above buildTypes

Comment: @SumOney Inside the `android` brackets. You basically add two new options to it thats `jackOptions` and `compileOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in here -> https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html Lambdas should be supported. You should check your SDK version, and upgrade it if needed.

Comment: I have latest version 25,0.1

Comment: And what JDK do you use ?

Comment: I have java version 8, I am not to sure how I can check the jdk version

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Comment: It says: jdk1.8.0_101